# Simulate a handwritten signature in Silverlight: (e.g. A pen progressively draws the lines)

Tags: silverlight, animation, silverlight-3.0, fonts, silverlight-4.0

I'd like to have Silverlight draw the blue "L" and "C" in the image below, preferably in a way that the thickness of the line is maintained and speeds/up slows/down at the correct locations to simulate a handwritten signature.

[image]
<sub>(source: [lamontconsulting.com](http://lamontconsulting.com/lc.JPG))</sub>

Can anyone point me to the right way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: That could be done using Blend, but it's a little long to explain and this type of animation is suprisingly complicated to my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first this is to take this raster graphic and turn it vector. There are different ways to do that, but I find Adobe Illustrator to be the best. It's got a feature called LiveTrace that will do this for you ([PDF file](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator/pdfs/creating_vector_content.pdf)). After you've got that, you could import that into Expression Blend and turn it into XAML (a PathGeometry). Once in Blend, you can animate any which way you like. What you'd want for this is a key frame animation.

Comment: I have it as a vector, and can create a PathGeometry.  What I'm not sure is how to actually go about animating it.  Maybe this is a noob question, or I just cant figure out what I do between key frames